# Code-signing issue. Getting a Build failed, with no specific error

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

I have just signed up for the Apple Developer Program (ADC), and did all that is necessary to make an app run on the device itself.

*I created an empty project and succeeded in running it on my device.*

I am using [RouteMe](https://github.com/route-me/route-me) for my project, and inside my project are several sub projects.
The problem now, is after I build the project, I can run it on the Simulator, **but not on the device**.

[image]

It is weird that no reason is given. Anyone knows what this could be?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions about programming, development, and listing your apps on the App Store are off topic for Ask Different.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the build log. This will show the error causing the build to be marked as failed.

> **Xcode** > **View** (menu) > **Navigators** > **Show Log Navigator**

Within the log navigator, click on the last build. You will be presented with the build steps; control-click on one of the steps and select **Expand All Transcripts**.

At this point, you will see everything the build system did and the output from each command. The error will be within this text.